# $R/\mathfrak p$ not always a UFD

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I am looking for a nice counterexample that for a UFD $R$ and $\mathfrak p\subset R$ a prime ideal, $R/\mathfrak p$ is not always a UFD as well.

Answer (score 4):

Pick any finitely generated domain which is not a UDF and write it as a quotient of $\mathbb Z[X_1,\dots,X_n]$. The ideal will be prime.

Answer (score 3):

A good geometric example is $R=k[x,y]$ and $\mathfrak p=(y^2-x^3)$.