# Is the property of being a UFD preserved under quotients by prime ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring, integral-domain, unique-factorization-domains

Say we have a UFD A and a prime ideal P. Is A/P a UFD?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: What's $U$?${}{}$

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1023990/r-mathfrak-p-not-always-a-ufd.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not necessarily. $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]$ is a UFD, but $$\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]/(Z^2-XY)=\mathbb C[x,y,z]  $$ is not.

**Edit**
Although it is certainly possible to give an elementary proof of non UFDness based on the two different factorizations $z^2=xy$ of the same element, I can't resist the temptation to say that $\mathbb C[x,y,z]$ is not a UFD because its class group is $\mathbb Z/(2)$ ([Hartshorne](https://books.google.nl/books?id=3rtX9t-nnvwC&hl=fr), example 6.5.2, page 133), whereas a UFD has zero class group (Hartshorne, Proposition 6.2, page 131).

Comment: Thanks! What distinction are you making between these two rings when you write the indeterminates of one in capitals and of the other in lowercase, by the way?

Comment: Capital letters are for the indeterminates in $\mathbb C[X,Y,Z]$, whereas lowercase letters are the classes of those indeterminates modulo the ideal $(Z^2-XY)$,  namely  $x=X \operatorname {mod} (Z^2-XY)$ etc.

Comment: Alright. Also, I have an additional question: we know that integral domains arise as quotients by prime ideals, fields as quotients by maximal ideals, etc. What conditions can we place on an ideal to ensure that a quotient by it is a UFD?

Comment: I don't think there is such a criterion. Anyway, I'm sure that **I** don't know any.

Answer (score 14):

Not necessarily. $\Bbb{Z}[x]$ is a UFD, but
$$\Bbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+5) \cong \Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$$
is not.